# Need help identifying burnt SMD IC (DAR69)

Tags: integrated-circuit

Cars head unit stoped working (Takara CDV1270BT). Upon disassembly found a loose screw and a burnt SMD IC. Half of the marking on it was still visible (DAR??). Found what I believe to be a similar one on the same board (DAR69). Googled it but nothing.
What I gather from the way it burned like that, it must be a power IC of some sort.
So maybe someone with more knowledge in IC's can identify it and lead me in a direction for a replacement.

[image: similar IC on same board close up]

[image: burnt IC]

[image: similar IC DAR69]

Comment: It’s a transistor, not an ic!

Comment: Q denotes Transistor (not sure why, nor U for IC). This probably makes identifying Q67 easier.

Comment: Could be this one, marking “DAR” - https://www.mccsemi.com/product-detail/2SD1664-R . Pin arrangement would be BCE - can’t tell if that’s consistent with the circuit.